# 2 Drupal Sites and 1 CiviCRM

Tags: installation, multisite

I am looking for some advice on whats the best approach to implement two Drupal sites with different domain names + designs and link them to one CiviCRM.

I know multi-site for CiviCRM is on option but the process to install does not seem very straightforward. The two options I can think of are:

A. Two Separate Drupal sites with Two CiviCRM codebases linked to One CiviCRM Database

B. One Drupal Multi-site installation (sub-sites) with One CiviCRM installation & Codebase.

Can anyone tell me the pros and cons and which one offers more flexibility in the long run considering all the upgrades and improvements for CiviCRM and Drupal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a third option. You can use two drupal sites and a third site for civicrm.

On your Drupal sites use CiviMRF module to connect to your CiviCRM site.

I wrote a blog on how to do this: https://civicrm.org/blog/jaapjansma/using-civicrm-form-processor-extension-to-handle-form-submissions-from-an-external

Personally I would go for this option, because you keep your CRM seperate from your website. A website might require changes/redesign over time while a CRM needs to be stable and stay the same over time. And this way you can easily change/redesign your website without the fear of breaking anything in your crm.